# Spectrum of a $1$-parameter family of symmetric linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I am working with certain submanifolds of symmetric spaces and, using a construction in Terng-Thorbergson, we ended up in the following Hilbert space problem:

Let $H$ be a (real) Hilbert Space and $T_t:H \rightarrow H$ be a smooth $1$-parameter family of symmetric operators. Suppose that there is a finite-dimensional subespace $V$ of $H$ such that the spectrum of both $T_t$ and $T_t|_{V^\perp}$ does not depend on $t$. Is it true that the trace of $T_t|_V$ also does not depend on $t$?

Comment: you mean: spectrum of $T_t|_V$ does not depend on $t$?

Comment: @daw, I believe he really means the weaker statement about the trace of $T_t|_V$. Do you have any clue in this case?

Comment: @RenatoMoreira: Are the operators linear? Continuous? Defined everywhere, or just densely defined? In the latter case, do they have a common core? How should one understand the ambiguous sentence *"the spectrum of both $T_t$ and $T_t | _{V^\perp}$ does not depend on $t$"*?

Comment: @AlexM. I am working with Renato in the problem. In principle, all operators are defined in whole spaces, but if you have a more general answer, it might be useful. They are all linear. About the phrase you asked: every $T_t$ defines a subset of real numbers given by the spectrum. We know that this set does not depend on $t$. I.e. the spectra of $T_t$ and $T_s$ are the same. The same for the restriction to $V^\perp$.

Comment: You can take any family of operators and add to it some fixed operator with the spectrum $[-a,a]$ with large enough $a$ in an orthogonal space to hide all information you may have from the spectra of $T_t$, so, in effect, you have no assumptions and, therefore, no conclusions will follow.

Comment: @fedja Could you better explain in more details what you meant or, even better, give an specific example?